# Mailchimp listing only one RSS-Item

Tags: xml, email, drupal, rss, mailchimp

I have a problem extending my page with an RSS-Feed to be able to start an RSS-to-email campaign with Mailchimp.

According to the w3c-validator my feed is fine, but mailchimp accquires only the first item in the feed instead of all four.

The feed: http://odessa.duschko.de/de/ticketshop-v2/rss

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding a `pubDate` -- publication date -- to your items. This is an optional item for RSS, so it's valid without, but Mailchimp requires it, I believe.

If you're coding the feed yourself in PHP, bear in mind that [PHP's date formatting constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types) helpfully include `DATE_RSS`/`DateTime::RSS`.

Mailchimp also has [an example RSS feed](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/ive-posted-new-information-to-my-rss-feed-but-no-campaigns-have-been-sent) shown in one of their Support articles -- if you're still having problems, compare your feed to that example.

Also, note (from [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/mailchimp-is-pulling-in-all-of-my-posts-on-my-rss-feed)):

> When you first set up an RSS campaign
>   we will show the last post as an
>   example if you haven't added an
>   article in a few days. If this is your
>   first send, we'll only send the posts
>   from 24 hours before your campaign was
>   activated for daily, from the last 7
>   days for weekly, and the past 30 days
>   for monthly.

So I'm fairly sure that's why one of your posts is showing up -- because there's no publication date on any of them, Mailchip is just showing you the first one it finds as an example.

Comment: I have a pubDate in my feed (http://blog.piratelufi.com/feed/) but I still get only one item.

Comment: @kapitanluffy You feed looks fine. How are you testing that you're only getting one item? Bear in mind that the [MailChimp help](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/what-is-an-rss-to-email-campaign-and-how-to-i-set-one-up?t=1383465450&v=168&enc=2f340f743a2f370b8414ebede21dafcdf0879cb64ae837a639d9bf2174b293bf#first) now just says "When you first set up an RSS campaign we'll show the last post that was added to your feed as an example." If you've not actually sent a mail yet, you may just be seeing the single example post. (Try a test campaign with you as the only recipient and see what happens.)

Comment: @kapitanluffy potentially you have the feed set for monthly instead of Daily, that makes a difference.

Comment: still having an issue with this and my feed does have pubDate - I also sent a test email which only had one blog post referenced @kapitanluffy

Comment: @RobertTomasGIV You should probably post a new question with a full example of your feed in it—or at least one of the posts that's not showing up that you think should—mentioning this question and that you've already tried the advice here. (That way it's less likely to be closed as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to watch for is if the feed has been run before. e.g a daily send going out at 9 am.

If you preview an edit to the design it will only show new stories that haven't been sent out.